# How to drag and drop a table row randomly in HTML table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to drag and drop a table row randomly in a HTML table using jQuery (not using jQuery plugins).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: OP *did* say no plugins...but I wonder why not..? What is wrong with plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest first.
Do you consider jquery ui as a plugin ?

If no, then you should look for it's sortable method
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
They also have a droppable and draggable method.

With sortable, you can quickly add sortable behaviour to your table.
Since you need to be able to mix header rows and body rows, you might try the connectWith option:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr class="connectedSortable">
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
            <th>Column5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="connectedSortable">
            <td>item1</td>
            <td>item2</td>
            <td>item3</td>
            <td>item4</td>
            <td>item5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="connectedSortable">
            <td>item11</td>
            <td>item22</td>
            <td>item33</td>
            <td>item44</td>
            <td>item55</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('table tr').sortable({
                    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: hi, i able to drag and drop header in html table but i can't change the preceding column data for that header

Comment: @giri So, the question you are asking is not the one you want/need an answer to? Alrighty...